# Return value from map.forEach in dart?

Tags: dictionary, dart

I want to search for a value in a `Map`.

```
Map<String, dynamic> map;
dynamic someThing;

map.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
  if (value == someThing) {
    return value;
  }
});
```

but I get this warning:

> Don't assign to `void.dart(void_checks)`

how can I do it without getting this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get the warning is because the `return` statement is inside the submethod you have defined as an argument to the `forEach` method. But since this method has the signature of `void f(K key, V value)`, you will get a warning when you try returning some value.

So you can make it like this instead so you don't define a new submethod:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map;
dynamic someThing;

for (final value in map.values) {
  if (value == someThing) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of for-each in dart - the `map.forEach` is used to go through every element, and return something based on it (like turning an array of strings into a Cell for display).

What you want is a more regular `for (Value value in values)`, where you get more freedom what to do, and can return at any point :)

I think when I tried `map.forEach` wrongly last time I also got a different warning telling me also not to use it O.O